# Cannot Access WebService From HTML File (Internal 500 Error)

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, soap

I've done a few AJAX websites before, but never calling a WebService (ASMX) straight from an HTML page. When I try to access my WebService I keep getting an error message:

> soap:ReceiverSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Xml.XmlException:
>   Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ...

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with a target framework of 4.5. I know this is an internal error of 500 which means, it's a server issue.

HTML Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="todaysLoad"></div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     getTotals();
 });

 function getTotals() {
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
         url: "Services/worker.asmx?HelloWorld",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success: function (data) {
             $("#todaysLoad").html(data.d);
         },
         error: function (error) {
             $("#todaysLoad").html(error.responseText);
         }
     });
 }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

WebService Code:

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    /// <summary>The Worker WebService will act as a mediator between database and client</summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [ScriptService]
    public class worker : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Today is Tuesday";
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"></jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I can successfully copy and paste the WebService URL and browse to it in my browser. I can even Invoke the HelloWorld() method. When I try to call the WebService from my HTML page, I cannot access it.

I did install the AJAX Control Toolkit (NuGet) in my solution.

Any ideas? Or, is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried sending it without the data?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried using `data: ""`, but still no luck

Comment: Just a quick update. I created a whole new ASP.NET WebForms project in Visual Studio 2015, imported JSON, jQuery, and AJAX NuGet Packages in the solution. Added a WebService, and wrote a simple AJAX call in JavaScript from my ASPX web forms page. The results, I'm still getting the SOAP exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
 url: "Services/worker.asmx?HelloWorld",
```

To this:

```
 url: "Services/worker.asmx/HelloWorld",
```

Comment: God bless you Sir! That was the solution! A typo, which I still can't believe caused so much problems. :-)